# If data exists in the table, do not save again

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.5.3, I have a form and with below function I trying to check if data exists with email key:

```
// EMAIL
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');

// TABLE
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'new_table';

//CHECK IF EMAIL EXISTS
$email_exists = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE form_email = $email";
$email_exists_results = $wpdb->get_results($email_exists);

// IF EMAIL DOES NOT EXISTS, REGISTER EMAIL    
if (count($email_exists_results) == 0) {
    $data = array(
        'form_email' => $email,
);
$wpdb->insert($tablename, $data);

} else {
    // IF EMAIL EXISTS, SEND MAIL
    wp_mail();
}
```

Above code is saving an existing email again in the table.

How can I not save the duplicate email in the table?

Comment: most likely your query fails due to missing quotes around $email and you should use parametrized queries to prevent SQL injections

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I was missing the single quotes around `$email` in the query.

Comment: It will be great, if you can tell me how to use parametrized queries in this example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
global $wpdb;
// get_var returns a single value 
$count = $wpdb->get_var(
// prepare takes care of parameters
// Select count() retuns a scalar value not the whole row
  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM %s WHERE form_email = '%s'",
    $wpdb->prefix . 'new_table',
    filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email')
  )
);
// Using strict comparison to avoid implicit type conversion 
if ($count === 0)
{
    // Email not in the db
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Not saving data with the above code. This is working `$email_exists = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE form_email = $email";
$email_exists_results = $wpdb->get_results($email_exists);

// IF EMAIL DOES NOT EXISTS, REGISTER EMAIL    
if (count($email_exists_results) == 0) {`